# I cant start apache with my Public IP address in Listen Configuration

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ip, port, amazon-ec2

I am currently using AWS Ec2 ubuntu (20.04) instance.
I have installed apache2 and configuring the Listen directive for apache.
But, i cant give the public IP address of my Ec2 instance in "Listen IP:port" directive. when i give the PUBLIC IP address in the IP field, apache fails to start.
I am getting error as below,
"Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details".
But it works when i give the private IP address and port combination for Listen directive.
Anybody knows Why?

Comment: You're not giving us the actual error, just what systemd burps. However, perhaps either that IP address does not exist on the system, or, that there is already something running  on that tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EC2 instance does not know the public address associated with it as that is mapped outside the EC2 instance and "reverse NAT" is used to map the external IP to the instance at a "virtual router" level.

As there is no external address on the EC2, Apache has nothing to bind to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation.